# how can I create a URL/site to send a HTTP 204 or HTTP 403 response?

Tags: objective-c, http, servlets, post, ios7

I'm trying to create an app with a login page to POST to a url and return a status code.  For now the app is to call a URL that returns a HTTP 204 or HTTP 403 response.  How is this done? Do I need to create/implement a servlet?

Comment: Do you need test URLs which return HTTP 204 or 403 responses to the app? Or are you trying to create a web service which return these responses?

Comment: Test URLs that return responses to the app I think.  Sorry I am new to app development and I don't know always know exactly how to word my question/terminology

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created a servlet using Maven/Eclipse/Tomcat and used HttpServletResponse

Answer (score 0):

You certainly can implement your own web service to return those HTTP responses.

For testing your app you can use services like [httpbin.org](http://httpbin.org/)

For example: To get a 403 response, simply send a request to `http://httpbin.org/status/403`